# NASM Error Parsing, Instruction Expected

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572021/problems-with-winasm-and-zen-of-assembly) but I changed assemblers and the question almost entirely changed, so in an effort to avoid question clutter I'm posting an entirely new question. Anyways, long story short, I'm on Windows 7 and I just installed NASM, and I'm trying to assemble a code listing from a book called Zen of Assembly by Michael Abrash. Here's the code for the listing:

```
;
; *** Listing 2-1 ***
;
; The precision Zen timer (PZTIMER.ASM)
;
; Uses the 8253 timer to time the performance of code that takes
; less than about 54 milliseconds to execute, with a resolution
; of better than 10 microseconds.
;
; By Michael Abrash 4/26/89
;
; Externally callable routines:
;
;  ZTimerOn: Starts the Zen timer, with interrupts disabled.
;
;  ZTimerOff: Stops the Zen timer, saves the timer count,
;   times the overhead code, and restores interrupts to the
;   state they were in when ZTimerOn was called.
;
;  ZTimerReport: Prints the net time that passed between starting
;   and stopping the timer.
;
; Note: If longer than about 54 ms passes between ZTimerOn and
;   ZTimerOff calls, the timer turns over and the count is
;   inaccurate. When this happens, an error message is displayed
;   instead of a count. The long-period Zen timer should be used
;   in such cases.
;
; Note: Interrupts *MUST* be left off between calls to ZTimerOn
;   and ZTimerOff for accurate timing and for detection of
;   timer overflow.
;
; Note: These routines can introduce slight inaccuracies into the
;   system clock count for each code section timed even if
;   timer 0 doesn't overflow. If timer 0 does overflow, the
;   system clock can become slow by virtually any amount of
;   time, since the system clock can't advance while the
;   precison timer is timing. Consequently, it's a good idea
;   to reboot at the end of each timing session. (The
;   battery-backed clock, if any, is not affected by the Zen
;   timer.)
;
; All registers, and all flags except the interrupt flag, are
; preserved by all routines. Interrupts are enabled and then disabled
; by ZTimerOn, and are restored by ZTimerOff to the state they were
; in when ZTimerOn was called.
;

Code    segment word public 'CODE'
    assume  cs:Code, ds:nothing
    public  ZTimerOn, ZTimerOff, ZTimerReport

;
; Base address of the 8253 timer chip.
;
BASE_8253       equ 40h
;
; The address of the timer 0 count registers in the 8253.
;
TIMER_0_8253        equ BASE_8253 + 0
;
; The address of the mode register in the 8253.
;
MODE_8253       equ BASE_8253 + 3
;
; The address of Operation Command Word 3 in the 8259 Programmable
; Interrupt Controller (PIC) (write only, and writable only when
; bit 4 of the byte written to this address is 0 and bit 3 is 1).
;
OCW3            equ 20h
;
; The address of the Interrupt Request register in the 8259 PIC
; (read only, and readable only when bit 1 of OCW3 = 1 and bit 0
; of OCW3 = 0).
;
IRR         equ 20h
;
; Macro to emulate a POPF instruction in order to fix the bug in some
; 80286 chips which allows interrupts to occur during a POPF even when
; interrupts remain disabled.
;
MPOPF macro 
    local   p1, p2
    jmp short p2
p1: iret            ;jump to pushed address & pop flags
p2: push    cs      ;construct far return address to
    call    p1      ; the next instruction
    endm

;
; Macro to delay briefly to ensure that enough time has elapsed
; between successive I/O accesses so that the device being accessed
; can respond to both accesses even on a very fast PC.
;
DELAY   macro
    jmp $+2
    jmp $+2
    jmp $+2
    endm

OriginalFlags       db  ?   ;storage for upper byte of
                    ; FLAGS register when
                    ; ZTimerOn called
TimedCount      dw  ?   ;timer 0 count when the timer
                    ; is stopped
ReferenceCount      dw  ?   ;number of counts required to
                    ; execute timer overhead code
OverflowFlag        db  ?   ;used to indicate whether the
                    ; timer overflowed during the
                    ; timing interval
;
; String printed to report results.
;
OutputStr   label   byte
        db  0dh, 0ah, 'Timed count: ', 5 dup (?)
ASCIICountEnd   label   byte
        db  ' microseconds', 0dh, 0ah
        db  '$'
;
; String printed to report timer overflow.
;
OverflowStr label   byte
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '****************************************************'
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '* The timer overflowed, so the interval timed was  *'
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '* too long for the precision timer to measure.     *'
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '* Please perform the timing test again with the    *'
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '* long-period timer.                               *'
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '****************************************************'
    db  0dh, 0ah
    db  '$'

;********************************************************************
;* Routine called to start timing.                  *
;********************************************************************

ZTimerOn    proc    near

;
; Save the context of the program being timed.
;
    push    ax
    pushf
    pop ax          ;get flags so we can keep
                    ; interrupts off when leaving
                    ; this routine
    mov cs:[OriginalFlags],ah   ;remember the state of the
                    ; Interrupt flag
    and ah,0fdh         ;set pushed interrupt flag
                    ; to 0
    push    ax
;
; Turn on interrupts, so the timer interrupt can occur if it's
; pending.
;
    sti
;
; Set timer 0 of the 8253 to mode 2 (divide-by-N), to cause
; linear counting rather than count-by-two counting. Also
; leaves the 8253 waiting for the initial timer 0 count to
; be loaded.
;
    mov al,00110100b        ;mode 2
    out MODE_8253,al
;
; Set the timer count to 0, so we know we won't get another
; timer interrupt right away.
; Note: this introduces an inaccuracy of up to 54 ms in the system
; clock count each time it is executed.
;
    DELAY
    sub al,al
    out TIMER_0_8253,al     ;lsb
    DELAY
    out TIMER_0_8253,al     ;msb
;
; Wait before clearing interrupts to allow the interrupt generated
; when switching from mode 3 to mode 2 to be recognized. The delay
; must be at least 210 ns long to allow time for that interrupt to
; occur. Here, 10 jumps are used for the delay to ensure that the
; delay time will be more than long enough even on a very fast PC.
;
    rept 10
    jmp $+2
    endm
;
; Disable interrupts to get an accurate count.
;
    cli
;
; Set the timer count to 0 again to start the timing interval.
;
    mov al,00110100b        ;set up to load initial
    out MODE_8253,al        ; timer count
    DELAY
    sub al,al
    out TIMER_0_8253,al     ;load count lsb
    DELAY
    out TIMER_0_8253,al     ;load count msb
;
; Restore the context and return.
;
    MPOPF               ;keeps interrupts off
    pop ax
    ret

ZTimerOn    endp

;********************************************************************
;* Routine called to stop timing and get count.             *
;********************************************************************

ZTimerOff proc  near

;
; Save the context of the program being timed.
;
    push    ax
    push    cx
    pushf
;
; Latch the count.
;
    mov al,00000000b        ;latch timer 0
    out MODE_8253,al
;
; See if the timer has overflowed by checking the 8259 for a pending
; timer interrupt.
;
    mov al,00001010b        ;OCW3, set up to read
    out OCW3,al         ; Interrupt Request register
    DELAY
    in  al,IRR          ;read Interrupt Request
                    ; register
    and al,1            ;set AL to 1 if IRQ0 (the
                    ; timer interrupt) is pending
    mov cs:[OverflowFlag],al    ;store the timer overflow
                    ; status
;
; Allow interrupts to happen again.
;
    sti
;
; Read out the count we latched earlier.
;
    in  al,TIMER_0_8253     ;least significant byte
    DELAY
    mov ah,al
    in  al,TIMER_0_8253     ;most significant byte
    xchg    ah,al
    neg ax          ;convert from countdown
                    ; remaining to elapsed
                    ; count
    mov cs:[TimedCount],ax
; Time a zero-length code fragment, to get a reference for how
; much overhead this routine has. Time it 16 times and average it,
; for accuracy, rounding the result.
;
    mov cs:[ReferenceCount],0
    mov cx,16
    cli             ;interrupts off to allow a
                    ; precise reference count
RefLoop:
    call    ReferenceZTimerOn
    call    ReferenceZTimerOff
    loop    RefLoop
    sti
    add cs:[ReferenceCount],8   ;total + (0.5 * 16)
    mov cl,4
    shr cs:[ReferenceCount],cl  ;(total) / 16 + 0.5
;
; Restore original interrupt state.
;
    pop ax          ;retrieve flags when called
    mov ch,cs:[OriginalFlags]   ;get back the original upper
                    ; byte of the FLAGS register
    and ch,not 0fdh     ;only care about original
                    ; interrupt flag...
    and ah,0fdh         ;...keep all other flags in
                    ; their current condition
    or  ah,ch           ;make flags word with original
                    ; interrupt flag
    push    ax          ;prepare flags to be popped
;
; Restore the context of the program being timed and return to it.
;
    MPOPF               ;restore the flags with the
                    ; original interrupt state
    pop cx
    pop ax
    ret

ZTimerOff endp

;
; Called by ZTimerOff to start timer for overhead measurements.
;

ReferenceZTimerOn   proc    near
;
; Save the context of the program being timed.
;
    push    ax
    pushf       ;interrupts are already off
;
; Set timer 0 of the 8253 to mode 2 (divide-by-N), to cause
; linear counting rather than count-by-two counting.
;
    mov al,00110100b    ;set up to load
    out MODE_8253,al    ; initial timer count
    DELAY
;
; Set the timer count to 0.
;
    sub al,al
    out TIMER_0_8253,al ;load count lsb
    DELAY
    out TIMER_0_8253,al ;load count msb
;
; Restore the context of the program being timed and return to it.
;
    MPOPF
    pop ax
    ret

ReferenceZTimerOn   endp

;
; Called by ZTimerOff to stop timer and add result to ReferenceCount
; for overhead measurements.
;

ReferenceZTimerOff proc near
;
; Save the context of the program being timed.
;
    push    ax
    push    cx
    pushf
;
; Latch the count and read it.
;
    mov al,00000000b        ;latch timer 0
    out MODE_8253,al
    DELAY
    in  al,TIMER_0_8253     ;lsb
    DELAY
    mov ah,al
    in  al,TIMER_0_8253     ;msb
    xchg    ah,al
    neg ax          ;convert from countdown
                    ; remaining to amount
                    ; counted down
    add cs:[ReferenceCount],ax
;
; Restore the context of the program being timed and return to it.
;
    MPOPF
    pop cx
    pop ax
    ret

ReferenceZTimerOff endp

;********************************************************************
;* Routine called to report timing results.             *
;********************************************************************

ZTimerReport    proc    near

    pushf
    push    ax
    push    bx
    push    cx
    push    dx
    push    si
    push    ds
;
    push    cs  ;DOS functions require that DS point
    pop ds  ; to text to be displayed on the screen
    assume  ds:Code
;
; Check for timer 0 overflow.
;
    cmp [OverflowFlag],0
    jz  PrintGoodCount
    mov dx,offset OverflowStr
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    jmp short EndZTimerReport
;
; Convert net count to decimal ASCII in microseconds.
;
PrintGoodCount:
    mov ax,[TimedCount]
    sub ax,[ReferenceCount]
    mov si,offset ASCIICountEnd - 1
;
; Convert count to microseconds by multiplying by .8381.
;
    mov dx,8381
    mul dx
    mov bx,10000
    div bx      ;* .8381 = * 8381 / 10000
;
; Convert time in microseconds to 5 decimal ASCII digits.
;
    mov bx,10
    mov cx,5
CTSLoop:
    sub dx,dx
    div bx
    add dl,'0'
    mov [si],dl
    dec si
    loop    CTSLoop
;
; Print the results.
;
    mov ah,9
    mov dx,offset OutputStr
    int 21h
;
EndZTimerReport:
    pop ds
    pop si
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    MPOPF
    ret

ZTimerReport    endp

Code    ends
    end
```

I added nasm.exe to my path, saved this file as listing1.asm, and tried to use the following CMD command to assemble it:

```
nasm -f win32 listing1.asm
```

However, it didn't assemble, and instead gave me the following errors:

```
listing1.asm:50: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:51: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:82: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:83: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:95: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:99: error: symbol `endm' redefined
listing1.asm:114: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:115: error: comma expected after operand 4
listing1.asm:116: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:122: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:142: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:176: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:179: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:188: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:190: error: symbol `endm' redefined
listing1.asm:200: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:203: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:208: error: symbol `MPOPF' redefined
listing1.asm:212: error: symbol `ZTimerOn' redefined
listing1.asm:212: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:218: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:237: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:252: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:282: error: comma, colon or end of line expected
listing1.asm:292: error: symbol `MPOPF' redefined
listing1.asm:298: error: symbol `ZTimerOff' redefined
listing1.asm:298: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:304: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:316: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:322: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:327: error: symbol `MPOPF' redefined
listing1.asm:331: error: symbol `ReferenceZTimerOn' redefined
listing1.asm:331: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:338: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:350: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:352: error: symbol `DELAY' redefined
listing1.asm:363: error: symbol `MPOPF' redefined
listing1.asm:368: error: symbol `ReferenceZTimerOff' redefined
listing1.asm:368: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:374: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:386: error: symbol `assume' redefined
listing1.asm:386: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:392: error: comma, colon or end of line expected
listing1.asm:402: error: comma, colon or end of line expected
listing1.asm:426: error: comma, colon or end of line expected
listing1.asm:436: error: symbol `MPOPF' redefined
listing1.asm:439: error: symbol `ZTimerReport' redefined
listing1.asm:439: error: parser: instruction expected
listing1.asm:441: error: symbol `Code' redefined
listing1.asm:441: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Not sure what I should do here; I've tried googling around a little bit but haven't come up with anything. Anyone recognize these errors?

Comment: This is code for good old MS-DOS. It will not run under Windows 7, where you are not allowed to reconfigure the hardware from a user program.

Comment: Also related / probably a duplicate: [NASM ASM not being compiled properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44984337)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That assembly language is MASM, not NASM.

For starters, NASM segments are defined differently.

Instead of

```
Code    segment word public 'CODE'
```

we write

```
section .text
```

And that "ASSUME" declaration...  You must have an ancient book.  That is old, old MASM code.  Brings back memories from the early 1980s for me!

There are many differences between NASM and MASM, and your code needs quite a bit of work to port.  If you want to port that MASM code to NASM, see [MASM/NASM Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035747/masm-nasm-differences) or the NASM documentation or google "NASM vs MASM"

TL;DR: you are writing MASM code, not NASM.

Comment: My NASM requires

section

not

.section

Comment: Yep! Thanks for noticing my typo, just edited :)

Comment: @GavinWilliams: Just FYI, `.section` is a GNU assembler directive, like `.section .rodata`, or `.section .text` (for which `.text` is a shorthand on ELF targets; on others the appropriate section for code could be something else, so `.text` could be an alias for something else).  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html .  Totally different directive syntax from NASM in general.