# NASM ASM not being compiled properly?

Tags: assembly, g++, nasm, intel

I am following a tutorial and learning **x64 Intel Syntax Assembly** and I have this code sample that suppose to compile without issues but I am getting errors, so I cannot get started.

Code sample:

```
.code
ASM_Debug proc
    mov rax, 55
    ret
ASM_Debug endp
end
```

I am using **NASM** assembly compiler, using **MinGW (G++)** code compiler, if I compile using inline assembly using **x64 Intel Syntax MASM** I don't get any errors.

Could someone tell me what do I need to do?, what is the correct **NASM** command line to compile this code so I could get started learning. Thanks

My current command line is: nasm.exe -f elf64 Foo.asm -o Foo.o

PS: I am **NOT using Visual Studio IDE for development**, I don't want to hear anything about it.

PS2: I am developing/working on/for **Windows** OS, NOT Linux.

**Compilation errors**:

```
CoreASM.asm:1: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]
CoreASM.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
CoreASM.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected
CoreASM.asm:5: error: symbol `ASM_Debug' redefined
CoreASM.asm:5: error: parser: instruction expected
CoreASM.asm:6: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+orphan-labels]
```

Comment: Related / probable duplicate: [NASM Error Parsing, Instruction Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11572307), except it's about ancient 16-bit MASM code, not x86-64 MASM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written is in MASM syntax, which NASM doesn't support. You can tell because of the `PROC`/`ENDP` keywords, which are only in MASM (and TASM, which is mostly syntax-compatible with MASM).

So, this is MASM syntax:

```
.code
ASM_Debug proc
    mov rax, 55
    ret
ASM_Debug endp
end
```

And this is the same code translated to NASM syntax:

```
SECTION .text

ASM_Debug:
    mov rax, 55
    ret
```

Notice, in particular, that:

- The `.code` directive has been replaced by `SECTION .text`.
- The `PROC`/`ENDP` keywords have been eliminated, and a simple label is used to name the procedure. Procedures don't repeat their names at the end.
- There is no `END` directive at the end of the code file.

You can find multiple guides to syntactical differences between MASM and NASM online. [Here is a blog post by Dara Hazeghi](http://left404.com/2011/01/04/converting-x86-assembly-from-masm-to-nasm-3/) that looks pretty comprehensive.

Your command line for running NASM is also wrong because it's trying to build a Linux-format binary (`elf64` format). (You *can* build these in NASM on Windows, of course, but you won't be able to *run* them.) For 64-bit Windows, you want `win64`. So, it would be:

```
nasm.exe -f win64 Foo.asm -o Foo.obj
```

(Note that `.obj` is conventional for object files on Windows, not `.o`, although you can use either. The entire `-o` switch is actually optional; if you omit it, NASM will automatically name the object file with the standard extension and the same name as our input source file.)

But, if you're trying to *learn* how to program in assembly, you really need to find a tutorial that uses syntax *identical* to what your assembler expects. If you want to use NASM as your assembler, then find a tutorial that also uses NASM. Or, if you want to use the MASM tutorial, then use MASM as your assembler. [Version 8 of MASM can be downloaded here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654) for non-commercial use; it isn't the newest version, but it's perfectly suitable for learning. However, that's the 32-bit version. If you want to assemble 64-bit code, you'll need the x86-64 version, with the filename `ml64.exe`. I don't know anywhere you can download this separately, but it *is* included with the Windows SDK. At least, I know it was included with the [Windows 7 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279); I'm not sure if it's still there in the latest Windows 10 SDKs, but I think so.